# Passing new argument to current process

Tags: .net, wpf, process, .net-5

My program is a launcher. It launches a game with some arguments (UI, server to connect).

```
CurrentProcess = Process.Start(@"path/to/the/game.exe", argumentsList);
```

The game provides a console where those arguments are used.

I want to reuse that same process, meaning I dont want to kill it then reopen it with the new arguments.

Is it possible to pass a new argument in the `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` of the `CurrentProcess` object while keeping the game alive ?

```
if (CurrentProcess != null)
{
     CurrentProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "new arguments to use";
     CurrentProcess.Reuse(); // something like this
}
```

Comment: The process you've launched must provide whatever means of interprocess communication

Answer (score 0):

ProcessStartInfo is only used when the process is started. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=net-6.0), "After you start the process, changing these values has no effect". It can not be used to pass arguments to the process during execution after the process has been started. There are other methods to communicate with an executing process such as named pipes, WCF, or .NET Remoting. [Here](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/local-machine-interprocess-communication-with-net) is a more extensive review of different interprocess communication options.